# Adapt spinner to send selection

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am new to Android and Java. I need to adapt the following line, that is of an edittext to spinner:

```
myIDspinner.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
```

I tried doing it in the following way, but did not work:

```
myIDspinner.setSelection(sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following to set the item

1. First add item to `ArrayAdapter`
2. Get the position of the item by passing data

   ```
    mySpinner.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getPosition("EditextData"));
   ```

Comment: Hi, getPosition show me this:
Non-static method getPosition(T) cannot be referenced from a static context.

thnk

Comment: It's `ArrayAdapter` method, pass the content it will search and get the position and by the position use `Spinner.setSelection(position)` to set the item

Answer (score -1):

You should create a class named data for example store the username in that class

then create an array adapter

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>

(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CLASSNAME.stringArray);
                     ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  sp.setAdapter(ad);
```

this should let ur string appear in spinner